# make a foreach select menu form sticky

Tags: php, foreach, sticky

I want it so that when people make a selection in my form, the selection they made stays after the form is submitted, or if there was an error in the form, the submitted fields still display their choices. I have tried a lot of things and can't get it to work. I looked for about 30 minutes on Stackoverflow and can't find an answer to this.

```
<form action="article_rating.php" method="post" class="formbox2"><table class="borderie" width="100%" align="center">
<?php 
$ratingarray = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Make a Selection');
?>
<p><tr><td align="left"><label for="readable" class="label">Readability Factor- Indicate if you feel this is article is easily readable</label></td><td align="right"><select name="readable">

<?php
foreach($ratingarray as $value){
    echo '<option value="'.$value .'"';
    echo ' selected="selected"'; 
echo '>' . $value . '</option>';
}
?>

</select>
</td></tr></p>
<p><tr><td align="left"><label for="originality" class="label">Originality Factor- Indicate how original you feel this article is.</label></td><td align="right"><select name="originality">
<?php
foreach($ratingarray as $value){
    echo '<option value="'.$value .'"';
    echo ' selected="selected"'; 
echo '>' . $value . '</option>';
}
?>
</select></td></tr></table></form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't echo `selected="selected"` for every option. Use an `if` condition to see if a value for each field was provided previously, and only echo selected if the value in the current iteration of the loop matches.

Example (assumes you're posting to the same page):

```
// In your loop
if (isset($_POST['readable'] && $_POST['readable'] == $value) {
  // echo selected
}
```